# How to get column value typeof(any array) from DataRow

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have DataTable which contains 4 columns:

```
DataColumn[] dc = new DataColumn[]
            {
                new DataColumn("Programname",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("X-Coordinate",typeof(double[])),
                new DataColumn("Y-Coordinate",typeof(double[])),
                new DataColumn("Z-Coordinate",typeof(double[])),
            };
```

Then I created one row:

```
DataRow row = ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].NewRow();
            row["Programname"] = "1";
            row["X-Coordinate"] = new double[]{ 1.23, 4.56, 7.89 };
            row["Y-Coordinate"] = new double[]{ 123, 451, 7.89 };
            row["Z-Coordinate"] = new double[] { 0.00, 1.11, 13.13 };    
 ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].Rows.Add(row);
```

And now i want to get value from this row:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ProgramDataSet.Tables)
            {                    
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3}", dr.ItemArray[0], dr.ItemArray[1], dr.ItemArray[2], dr.ItemArray[3]);    
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

As output I'm getting : `1 System.Double[] System.Double[] System.Double[]`

instead of: 1 1.23 4.56 7.89 etc

How can I get value from dr.ItemArray[1], dr.ItemArray[2], dr.ItemArray[3]?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dr["Programname"]` access like this or `dr[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You could get `Programname` like `dr["Programname"]`, but for `X-Coordinate` you could cast `dr["X-Coordinate"]`  to `double[]` and use [**string.Join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) to concatenates elements of arrays like a `string` for `console.Write()`, like the following code :

```
Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3}", dr["Programname"], string.Join(",", (double[])dr["X-Coordinate"]), 
                    string.Join(",", (double[])dr["Y-Coordinate"]), string.Join(",", (double[])dr["Z-Coordinate"]));
```

**Update as per comment**

```
int columnIndex = 0;
var columns = ProgrammsForLaser.ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].Columns;
dataGridView1.ColumnCount  = columns.Count;

foreach (DataColumn dc in columns) 
{ 
    dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].Name = dc.ColumnName;
    columnIndex++;
} 
foreach (DataRow dr in ProgrammsForLaser.ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].Rows) 
{ 
    string[] row = { dr[0].ToString(), string.Join(",", (double[])dr[1]), string.Join(",", (double[])dr[2]), string.Join(",", (double[])dr[3]) };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row); 
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks this was very very helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can help me further? Now I'm trying to show the data in dataGridView so that it looks like this:
|Programname|X-Coordinate 1|Y-Coodinate 1|Z-Coordinate 1| X-Coordinate 2....  

          1           1.23        123         0.00           4.56
Could you tell me how to realize it?

Comment: @pahager if you have tried any code please share it, i don't have experience with dataGrid but i can help if i see the code.

Comment: foreach (DataColumn dc in ProgrammsForLaser.ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].Columns)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            }


 foreach (DataRow dr in ProgrammsForLaser.ProgramDataSet.Tables["Standard"].Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            }

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make a helper method.

```
string Join(object value)
{
    if (value is double[] array)
    {
        return string.Join(",", array);
    }
    return value.ToString();
}
```

Use it like follows.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
        Join(dr[0]), Join(dr[1]), Join(dr[2]), Join(dr[3])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access like this,

`dr["Programname"]`  or `dr[0]`

Comment: Didn't really get what you mean. How will this help me to get value for example from Column "X-Coordinate"?

Comment: `dr["X-Coordinate"]` or `dr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is the correct output. If you observe **dr.ItemArray[1]/ dr.ItemArray[2]/ dr.ItemArray[3]** there return types are of type double[]. In order to print elements u need to iterate.

If u pass dr.ItemArray[1] in console, by default tostring() method is called on the type to return its fully qualified name thats what u are getting as output.

U should try something like to get values

```
foreach(double value in  (dr.ItemArray[1] as double[])){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I got what you mean.
When I am trying your code I'm getting error:
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @pahager I have updated the post. U need to cast it to double[].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your data structure is weird. You have columns that contain multiple values (since they contains arrays of double). This is a structure that will be very difficult to store in a real database, and even to represent to the users.

If your arrays contain always the same number of doubles, then split them into more columns, like X-Coordinate-1, X-Coordinate-2... which each will contain one double value. That way a simple iteration will provide you all information you need and you can easily send that into a regular database.

If the number of elements in your arrays are variable from one row to another, maybe you need to create another table and join the two. The way to do this is far beyond the scope of this answer, but I suggest you look into it.

If for whatever reason you cannot switch to one of these two forms, then you need to iterate into each array in order to display the values. Since code could become fairly ugly, a nice way would be to create a helper method, which would be an extension :

```
public static class DoubleArrayExtension
{
    public static string PrintArray(this double[] array)
    {
        return string.Join(array, ", ");
    }
}
```

Then you would use it as follows :

```
Console.Write("{0} {1} {2} {3}", 
                dr.ItemArray[0], 
                ((double[])dr.ItemArray[1]).PrintArray(), 
                ((double[])dr.ItemArray[2]).PrintArray(), 
                ((double[])dr.ItemArray[3]).PrintArray());
```

Comment: The reason why I decided to use an array is that the number of coordinates can be different depending on the program. And I thought why not just create 3 columns with arrays in them.
Thanks for your help!